# MERGE UPDATE Statement in SQL inserting new rows

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, merge

I'm using a MERGE-UPDATE statement in spark-SQL to update data in a table based on another table. However, I noticed that when I run the MERGE statement more than once, additional rows are inserted into source_table. This behavior is unexpected for me, I would expect that update would only *update* rows and not insert.

**What I've tried**

My MERGE statement looks as follows:

```
MERGE INTO my_db.my_table dest_table USING change_table 
    ON dest_table.key_1 = change_table.key_1 AND dest_table.key_2 = change_table.key_2
    AND change_table.SYS_CHANGE_OPERATION = 'U' 
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE 
        SET (dest_table.field_a = change_table.field_a, dest_table.field_b = change_table.field_b)
```

**My Question**

Is there something wrong in the syntax of my merge statement? Why is it inserting new rows, instead of only updating rows that are already present?

Comment: pls check if the key columns on which dest_table & change_table are joined, are matching.

Comment: What do you mean specifically? This is what the ON part in my query is doing right?

Comment: what table format are you using?

Comment: I'm using DELTA

Comment: what i mean is `dest_table.key_1 = change_table.key_1 AND dest_table.key_2 = change_table.key_2
    AND change_table.SYS_CHANGE_OPERATION = 'U' ` condition decides insert or update. Merge is inserting means this condition is not working or its resulting to false.

Comment: I see, could this also be because dest_table has duplicate keys? Does MERGE UPDATE insert rows when the condition is not satisfied?

Answer (score 2):

The reason your query is allowing to do insert operation might be due to condition specified for the change_table.SYS_CHANGE_OPERATION column. This condition is being evaluated to 'I'(indicating an insert operation).

Since you mentioned that additional rows are being inserted into the source_table when you run the MERGE statement multiple times, it suggests that the condition change_table.SYS_CHANGE_OPERATION = 'I' is always evaluating to true for those rows, even after the initial update operation.

To resolve this issue, Verify that the values in the SYS_CHANGE_OPERATION column accurately represent the operation performed. Ensure that only the relevant rows have the value 'I' for insert operations.

Comment: I'm sorry, rows that ought to be updated have a 'U', always. It was a typo.